# Standalone Alert in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to display an alert, when I may not have a handle on a ViewController?

I'm creating a centralized function for logging errors to the console, to my database, and ideally I'd like to pop up a notification for the user. I'd rather not have to pass in a ViewController every time I log an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca present it from your `rootViewController` or the current displayed `viewController`.
Since you start your application at least you have a UIWindow object and most 
probably at least the `rootViewController` for that window.

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController
```

You can present it from here anywhere in your code, just make a method an extension in UIApplication or UIViewController.
Or you can search for the top most view controller. Again you can make an extension in `UIApplication` that present your alert from there:

```
class func topViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let rootViewController = rootViewController else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let presented = rootViewController.presentedViewController else {
            return rootViewController
        }

        switch presented {
        case let navigationController as UINavigationController:
            return topViewController(rootViewController: navigationController.viewControllers.last)

        case let tabBarController as UITabBarController:
            return topViewController(rootViewController: tabBarController.selectedViewController)

        default:
            return topViewController(rootViewController: presented)
        }
    }
```

Taking a an alert view as an example:

```
extension UIApplication {
     static func presentAlert(with title: String, message: String) {
         guard let rootVc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController else {
         return
      }
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        rootVc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
}
```

Comment: This will fail if `rootVC` is already presenting some other view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy yes the first case, but the second will iterate through all VC hierarchy and will present the VC on an already presented VC, it sounds pretty ugly :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can always add a view on the window. Search about adding view to the window of the application.

Comment: Same as what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView and add it as the frontmost subview of the window (which is always readily available).

This could be a UIView subclass that loads from a nib, that has a label and a dismiss button, and so on. Thus it can simple and self-contained.

I actually use something like this for debugging purposes in my own apps. When I `print` to the console I also put up a temporary UILabel in front of everything so that I see what I'm logging.